# bootstrap display text and input in one line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input

I don`t know how display input and text in one line. Of course I want display every input with text in another line. Can help me?

```
   <form action="" method="POST" role="form"  name="" id="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-1" style="padding-left:0px;">
              <label>Przychody:</label>
              <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="przychody" value={$podatki[1]}>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-1" style="padding-left:0px;">
              <label>Koszty:</label>
              <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="koszty" value={$podatki[2]}>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  It's not clear what you are asking.  The raw HTML you provide will display the label beside its input, and then another label/input pair on the line below.

Comment: Come on, man, this ain't a forum! If you want to participate in the community you *really* should get to know the rules. One of the rules is questions are questions, answers are answers. So no 'solved' in the *question* title. It's enough that you marked the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I agree with you dandan78. I rollback the editing. @marcin_poland, answers get to the top of the list, by community votes and such. I beleive you were trying to help, but don't worry about that. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" role="form" name="" id="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="przychody" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Przychody:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="przychody" name="przychody" value={$podatki[1]}>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
        <label for="koszty" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Koszty:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="koszty" name="koszty" value={$podatki[2]}>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For further information please consult the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bootstrap Form Builder: https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder

It's very helpful in most cases